# Wordpress multilingual structure issue

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress website in which for multiple languages I am using plugin "q-translator-x" for changing language from English to Spanish. Now the problem which I am facing now is. When my website is in English, it's layout coming perfectly fine. But when I change it into Spanish some parts of my website structure getting changes. Mainly text will move to underneath header bar.

Here are the following screenshots which help you to know much better understanding of my issue.

I would appreciate if you can help me out from this problem.

Screenshot of English version, which is perfectly fine:

[image]

In Spanish version, the issue highlighted in blue line

[image]

Comment: What have you tried to solve this so far? Have you compared the generated markup to spot the difference?

Comment: I have tried the white space remover plugin so that unwanted space has remove from my site.

Comment: If i try to add markup  for spanish version then it will affect the layout for english version.